# Capturar atual opção selecionada - multipleselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dado um campo multiple select, como obtenho, via javascript, o valor do option que foi selecionado por último (atual)?

Eu tentei utilizar a expressão abaixo, porém é retornado o último valor (em ordem alfabética) da lista de itens selecionados, e não necessariamente o último selecionado.

```
$("option:selected:last",this)).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, assim como "charlietfl" achei que isso seria um simples exercicio de treino, mas é bem chatinho.

Recuperar o valor do select não é um problema, o problema é justamente como eles são armazenados na array.

Esse fiddle resolve seu problema:
http://jsfiddle.net/wYxUt/1/

Post original do fiddle:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/last-selected-option-on-multiple-select-list